# Issue while create Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, subnet

I want to create an environment with the AWS Elastic Beanstalk and receive the following error:

```
Creating Auto Scaling group failed Reason: You must use a valid fully-formed launch template. No default subnet for availability zone: 'us-east-1c'. (Service: AmazonAutoScaling; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 72709cac-b1af-4572-86d1-400999530c30; Proxy: null)


Stack named 'awseb-e-magk463eka-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBV2LoadBalancer, AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].
```

This informs that I need a default subnet for the availability zone: 'us-east-1c'. Why do I will need that for the Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Because ALBs are highly available and they are deployed in each AZ of a particular region.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while trying to create an ElasticBeanstalk in the Mumbai region.

```
Creating Auto Scaling group failed Reason: You must use a valid fully-formed launch template. No default subnet for availability zone: 'ap-south-1a'
```

Later I switched to the North Virginia region (us-east-1) and that resolved my issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error but only in the regions that I had used before, so it was highly probable that the error was due to something I did and not because of the regions.

The problem was that I had deleted my default subnets and the internet gateway. If this also happens to you, create default subnets by using:

```
aws ec2 create-default-subnet --availability-zone ap-northeast-1b
```

Then modify the route table to connect to the internet gateway.